# How to get a product with no shipping class

Tags: php, woocommerce, product, shipping-method

I have found a code in stackoverflow that I slighltly modified to show for each product the shipping class and its associated cost and this 'hard coded' as I only have 2 shipping classes depending on product size for just one shipping method.

I can show the class and 'echo' the price associated to this class for products who have a shipping class, however if there is no class I am getting stuck on how to get the 'string value' of no class products or anything else that can target them.

Below is the code maybe someone can help, (I have tried '', null), I am really new with PHP...

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'display_product_shipping_class', 15 );
function display_product_shipping_class(){
    global $product;
    
    $shipping_class = $product->get_shipping_class();
    if( ! empty($shipping_class) ) {
        $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $shipping_class, 'product_shipping_class' );
    
        if( is_a($term, 'WP_Term') ){
            echo '<p class="product-shipping-class">' . $term->name . '</p>';
            $myVar1 = "pavolum";
            $myVar2 = "pvolum";
            $myVar3 = "";
            if( $shipping_class==$myVar1){ 
                echo '<p class="tarif">Livraison à Tarif=10dt</p>';
            }
            if( $shipping_class==$myVar2){ 
                echo '<p class="tarif">Livraison à Tarif=15dt</p>';
            }
            if($shipping_class== null){
                echo '<p class="tarif">Livraison à Tarif=7dt</p>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if (is_null($shipping_class)) or, in case you get an empty string, if (empty($shipping_class))

Comment: Hello Carlos thanks for your answer but I have tried it as well, the problem is certainly as described by XceeD below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problem**

For a start, on line #5, you have the following condition which check if `$shipping_class` is different than empty before going forward:

```
if( ! empty($shipping_class) )
```

With this condition, you will never reach the third case where you compare `$shipping_class` with `$myVar1`, `$myVar2` and potentially `''` or `null`.

---

Reminder for possible empty values:

```
The following values evaluates to empty:

0
0.0
"0"
""
NULL
FALSE
array()
```

([Source for empty()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_var_empty.asp))

---

**Possible solutions**

A possible solution could be to check if `$shipping_class` is `empty()` and add a `else` statement to manage the case where it's empty/not defined.

Example with code:

```
if( ! empty($shipping_class) ) {
   // Do comparison with $myVar1 and $myVar2 here
}
else {
  // Manage case where $shipping_class is empty
}
```

Another possible solution could be to remove the check on `empty()` and manage the case with your second if, which should now be working as expected.

Comment: Thanks XceeD for your proposed solution I have not focused on first condition that check for non-emptiness.. Your remarks are perfectly explained and I think your proposed solution will work. Will check and tell. Again thank you so much

Comment: I confirm that it works fine by testing empty class with else statement as you suggested. Thank you very much!

Comment: Excellent! Don't forget to mark this answer as accepted to close the thread! @Mehdi

Comment: If you want, you could upvote Mr Mehdi's question, which is clear, and has provided his code attempt.

Comment: Thank you very much Loic that is also initialy your code that I used